# PHP upload image

Tags: php, image, upload

Alright I have way to much time invested in this. I am new to PHP programming and trying to grasp the basics, but I am a little lost as of last night I was able to get a PHP form to upload basic data like a name address and stuff to my (MySQL) server.

But today I said let's do the next step which would be an image to the server.
I have watched 3 videos on YouTube probably a 100 times just recoping code and trying it in so many different ways.

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxY3FR9doHI
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFZfJZ_WNC4&feature=relmfu
```

and still haven't been able to get it.

But long story short: I have a config.php file that connects to the server and here is the the code I'm running on the upload form page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Upload an image</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <form action="UploadContent.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  File:
    <input type="file" name="image"> <input type="submit" value="Upload">
  </form>
<?php

// connect to database
include"config.php";

// file properties
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if (!isset($file))
  echo "Please select a profile pic";
else
{
  $image = addslashes(file_get_content($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
  $image_name = addslashes($FILES['image']['name']);
  $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

  if ($image_size==FALSE)
    echo "That isn't a image.";
  else
  {
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO content VALUES ('','','','','','','','','','$image_name','$image',)");
  }
}
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

The reason for all the `'', '', '', ''` on the insert line is because I have the name in the 10th field and the image blob in the 11th and all the ones leading up to that are first name, last name and random stuff like that. How can I fix this? It is returning the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_get_content() in /home/content/34/9587634/html/WEBPAGE/UploadContent.php on line 22

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code overlooks calling the function move_uploaded_file() which would check whether the indicated file is valid for uploading.

You may wish to review a simple example at:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: hmm thank you but I'm lost on this part not I got ride of the error but I cant figure out how to get the file into my mysql server you claim move_upload_file but I cant seem to get that to work.

Comment: how to upload file store in a directory path?

Answer (score 6):

You need to add two new file one is index.html, copy and paste the below code and other is imageup.php which will upload your image

```
 <form action="imageup.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="banner" >
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>

 imageup.php
 <?php
 $banner=$_FILES['banner']['name']; 
 $expbanner=explode('.',$banner);
 $bannerexptype=$expbanner[1];
 date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
 $date = date('m/d/Yh:i:sa', time());
 $rand=rand(10000,99999);
 $encname=$date.$rand;
 $bannername=md5($encname).'.'.$bannerexptype;
 $bannerpath="uploads/banners/".$bannername;
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["banner"]["tmp_name"],$bannerpath);
 ?>
```

The above code will upload your image with encrypted name

Answer (score 4):

Change function `file_get_content()` in your code to `file_get_contents()` . You are missing 's' at the end of function name. That is why it is giving undefined function error.

[file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Remove last unnecessary comma after `$image` filed in line

```
"INSERT INTO content VALUES         ('','','','','','','','','','$image_name','$image',)
```

Comment: Thank you that got ride of my error now im not getting to output witch is odd

Comment: Wow Thank you for making me feel like an idiot not once but twice lol

Thank you seriously four hours for that

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to save the image in the server, and then save the URL in MYSQL database.

First of all, you should do more validation on your image, before non-validated files can lead to huge security risks.

1. Check the image

   ```
   if (empty($_FILES['image']))
     throw new Exception('Image file is missing');
   ```
2. Save the image in a variable

   ```
   $image = $_FILES['image'];
   ```
3. Check the upload time errors

   ```
   if ($image['error'] !== 0) {
      if ($image['error'] === 1) 
         throw new Exception('Max upload size exceeded');

      throw new Exception('Image uploading error: INI Error');
   }
   ```
4. Check whether the uploaded file exists in the server

   ```
   if (!file_exists($image['tmp_name']))
       throw new Exception('Image file is missing in the server');
   ```
5. Validate the file size (Change it according to your needs)

   ```
    $maxFileSize = 2 * 10e6; // = 2 000 000 bytes = 2MB
       if ($image['size'] > $maxFileSize)
           throw new Exception('Max size limit exceeded');
   ```
6. Validate the image (Check whether the file is an image)

   ```
    $imageData = getimagesize($image['tmp_name']);
        if (!$imageData) 
        throw new Exception('Invalid image');
   ```
7. Validate the image mime type (Do this according to your needs)

   ```
    $mimeType = $imageData['mime'];
    $allowedMimeTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'];
    if (!in_array($mimeType, $allowedMimeTypes)) 
       throw new Exception('Only JPEG, PNG and GIFs are allowed');
   ```

This might help you to create a secure image uploading script with PHP.

Code source: https://developer.hyvor.com/php/image-upload-ajax-php-mysql

Additionally, I suggest you use [MYSQLI prepared statements](https://developer.hyvor.com/php/prepared-statements) for queries to improve security.

Thank you.

Comment: empty($_FILES['image']) returns true also if file is not been uploaded. Array
(
    [name] => 
    [type] => 
    [tmp_name] => 
    [error] => 4
    [size] => 0
)

Comment: I get  `Undefined index: mime ` .is `mime` depricated?

Answer (score 2):

Simple PHP **file/image upload** code on same page.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table border="1px">
    <tr><td><input type="file" name="image" ></td></tr>
    <tr><td> <input type="submit" value="upload" name="btn"></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>

 <?php
   if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
     $image=$_FILES['image']['name']; 
     $imageArr=explode('.',$image); //first index is file name and second index file type
     $rand=rand(10000,99999);
     $newImageName=$imageArr[0].$rand.'.'.$imageArr[1];
     $uploadPath="uploads/".$newImageName;
     $isUploaded=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],$uploadPath);
     if($isUploaded)
       echo 'successfully file uploaded';
     else
       echo 'something went wrong'; 
   }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example of how an image file with certain restrictions (listed below) can be uploaded to the server.

- Existence of the image.
- Image extension validation
- Checks for image size.

  ```
  <?php
     $newfilename = "newfilename";

     if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
        $errors= array();
        $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
        $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

        $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");
        if(file_exists($file_name)) {
          echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
          }
        if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
           $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
        }

        if($file_size > 2097152){
           $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
        }

        if(empty($errors)==true){
          move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$newfilename.".".$file_ext);
          echo "Success";
          echo "<script>window.close();</script>";

        }

        else{
           print_r($errors);
        }
     }
  ?>
  <html>
     <body>

        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <input type="file" name="image" />
           <input type="submit"/>
        </form>

     </body>
  </html>
  ```

  Credit to [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm) page.

Comment: This line '  if(empty($errors)==true){ ' should be like '  if(!count($errors)){  ' because, this ' $errors= array(); ' is not empty. Whithout any error this is also the best way on 0 count.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$filetype=$_FILES['file']['type'];
if($filetype=='image/jpeg' or $filetype=='image/png' or $filetype=='image/gif')
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'dir_name/'.$filename);
$filepath="dir_name`enter code here`/".$filename;
}

?>
```

Comment: Code-only responses are considered low-quality. Please summarize what your code does by clicking on edit and adding some detail to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php 
 $target_dir = "images/";
    echo $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $post_tmp_img = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $post_imag = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($post_tmp_img,"../images/$post_imag");
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is very easy to upload file by php. In this code I am performing uploading task in same page that mean our html and php both code resides in the same file. This code generates new name of image name.

first of all see the html code

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="banner_image" >
 <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
```

now see the php code

```
<?php
$image_name=$_FILES['banner_image']['name'];
       $temp = explode(".", $image_name);
        $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
       $imagepath="uploads/".$newfilename;
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["banner_image"]["tmp_name"],$imagepath);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful for me