# October Cms - How can I save a png image using a frontend form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, octobercms

I want the user to be able to upload images to show them in pages.

I tried in different ways but I couldn't get the upload working.

Comment: can you provide a sample of what you've tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php upload image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465929/php-upload-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of you need latest build of October cms as it supports file upload using ajax Api.

```
{{ form_ajax('onUploadImage', { files: 'true',  flash: 'true', 'data-request-files':true, 'data-request-validate': true }) }}
    <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar" />
    <button type="submit" data-attach-loading>Upload</button>
{{ form_close() }}
```

> **files: 'true'**  is required.

now on your `component` or in you `page code section` you can write code

```
public function onUploadImage() {
    // Returns the signed in user
    $user = Auth::getUser();
    $user->avatar = \Input::file('avatar');
    $user->save();

    //this \Input::file('avatar'); do have file instance
    so with your model you can also do same 
    // $yourModel get your model instance
    $yourModel->fileRelation = \Input::file('file_input_name');
    $yourModel->save();
}
```

Inside your Model can add relation

```
public $attachOne = [
    'fileRelation' => 'System\Models\File'
];
```

it will allow you to upload file using AJAX if you need `POST` method to upload file please comment.