# I want to insert 3 images into a folder and path into mysql with new name

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload

I want to insert 3 images into a folder and path into mysql with a new name.

My table name is 'ict' with database 'ctg'. Table fields are id, image1, image2, image3.

Now I want to use a form containing three input type="file" and a submit button.

How is it possible with PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php upload image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465929/php-upload-image)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Below Database.php 

<?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "ctg";



    // Create connection
    connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$username,$password);
    function connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbuser,$dbpassword)
    {
        global $link;

        $link=mysql_connect ("$servername","$dbuser","$dbpassword");

        if(!$link){
                die("Could not connect to MySQL");
        }

        mysql_select_db("$dbname",$link) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error()); 
    }
    ?>

# Below File.php

    <?php
//error_reporting(0);

include("database.php");

 if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
    /* Concept Image */

    $aMyUploads = array();
    foreach ($_FILES as $key => $aFile) {
        for($i = 0; $i<count($aFile['error']); $i++){
            //echo $aFile['error'][$i]; exit;
            if(0 === $aFile['error'][$i]){
                    $uploadLocation = 'uploads/'.$aFile['name'][$i];
            }   
            if(0 === $aFile['error'][$i] && (false !== move_uploaded_file($aFile['tmp_name'][$i], $uploadLocation))){
                $aMyUploads[] = $uploadLocation;
            } else {
                $aMyUploads[] = '';
            }
        }   
    }

    if(is_array($aMyUploads)){
        $image1 = $aMyUploads[0]; 
        $image2 = $aMyUploads[1];
        $image3 = $aMyUploads[2];
        $qry = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ict` (`image1`, `image2`, `image3`) VALUES ('$image1', '$image2', '$image3')");
        //$ex =mysql_query($qry,$con);
    }else{
        echo "ERROR :: Not insert Please try";
    }
}
?>
<html>
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-4">IMAGE1</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-offset-0 col-md-4">
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="upload_files[]">
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-4">IMAGE2</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-offset-0 col-md-4">
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="upload_files[]">
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-4">IMAGE3</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-offset-0 col-md-4">
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="upload_files[]">
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-7 col-md-offset-4">
      <button type="submit" name="upload">Upload</button>
    </div> 
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, image path has not inserted into table ict. Images have uploaded only uploads file.

Comment: @Shyful I have fixed issue for  "image path has not inserted into table ict." Please check, let me know.