# Uploading an image to my server with an PHP API in Android Studio?

Tags: php, json, api

I'm trying to capture an image and that image upload it to a folder and a local or online database, but I can not implement that part in an API, I have this class and the API in php.

Class Image:

```
    <?php
require_once('exceptions/recordnotfoundexception.php');
require_once('connections/mysqlconnection.php');

class Image {

    private $idImage;    
    private $name;
    private $image;

    //getters
    public function getIdImage() { return $this->idImage; }
    public function setIImage($idImage) { $this->idImage = $idImage; }
    public function getName() { return $this->name; }
    public function setName($name) { $this->name = $name; }
    public function getImage() { return $this->image; }
    public function setImage($image) { $this->image = $image; }   

    public function __construct() {
        if(func_num_args() == 0) {
            $this->idImage = 0;
            $this->name = '';
            $this->image = '';
        }

    public function add() {
        $connection = MySqlConnection::getConnection();
        $statement = 'insert into photo(name, image) values (?, ?)';
        $command = $connection->prepare($statement);
        $command->bind_param('ss', $this->name, $this->image);
        $result = $command->execute();
        mysqli_stmt_close($command);
        $connection->close();
        return $result;
    }    
    }

Image controller

    <?php
    require_once("models/image.php");

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {        
        if(isset($_POST['name']) &&  isset($_POST['image'])) {        
            $parametersOk = true;
            $valuesOk = true;
            if ($valuesOk) 
            { 
                try 
                {
                    $image = new Image();
                }
                catch (RecordNotFoundException $ex) 
                {
                    $valuesOk = false;
                    echo json_encode(array(
                        'status' => 3,
                        'message' => $ex->getMessage()
                    ));
                }
            }
            if ($valuesOk) 
            {
                $image = new Image();
                $image->setName($_POST['name']);
                $image->setImage($_POST['image']);                
                if ($image->add())
                    echo json_encode(array(
                        'status' => 0,
                        'message' => 'Image added successfully'
                    ));
                else
                    echo json_encode(array(
                        'status' => 4,
                        'message' => 'Could not add Image'
                    ));
            }       
        }             
        else 
        {
            echo json_encode(array(
                'status' => 1,
                'message' => 'missing parameters'
            ));
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You can't upload an image in a database but can reference it with its name. This question might help to understand how to upload an image to server https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465929/php-upload-image

Comment: "I can not implement" - What steps are you taking? What happens when you try to save the image data? Is there an error message? What line of code is causing the error?

Comment: It's been awhile since I did image upload, but I believe you have to move the file from a temporary directory to the permanent directory. You should be able to save the image data to a `BLOB` column in a `MySQL` DB, but I'm not sure that's good practice. I believe it's better to save the image file & a filepath to it. I think using the BLOB column may be less performant. But again, it's been awhile, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @Reed Yeah, I tried a BLOB but it does not work for me, because it has a weight limit
Do you have mail so we can talk easier?

Comment: Sorry, I don't answer email in my free time. Feel free to ask more questions here in the comments and I'll answer as I'm able. [This](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) may be helpful for uploading files.

Comment: If you're particularly stuck or frustrated, don't forget to take breaks! I'm off to bed for now, though. Good luck!

Comment: @Reed thank you man, yeah hahah 
Yes, I really want to do what is in this link but I do not know how to fit it in my code, it's just that and I would have it already

Good night ;)