# How to display the original size of an image that was uploaded by a user?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm learning web development by creating a personal project from scratch. Basically I'd like to project a website similar to 9GAG (a user generated content website).
I got stuck at the process of displaying the uploaded image. The image is displayed but it adapts to the dimensions of the div element. I would like the opposite: the div to adapt to the image's original dimensions. 
I read that I should code some PHP that would get the image dimensions ( getImageSize() ) and then write JavaScript that would change the div's width and height based on the result from the PHP function.
I really don't know how these two would interact with each other.

So, do you have any suggestion or solution that would fit to my needs?

Thank you,
Marco

Comment: Do you plan on having them submit the image to a server, or do you want this all done locally on the client?

Comment: The first option - the users having to submit the image to a server

Comment: But can JavaScript get a variable from php?

Comment: I deleted my comment, see my answer below. No Server interaction needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` properties. No PHP needed.

```js
document.querySelector(`img`).addEventListener(`load`, function(){
  console.log(`width: ${this.naturalWidth}`);
  console.log(`height: ${this.naturalHeight}`);
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/logo-javascript-png-file-javascript-logo-png-1052.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

In general that is a very bad idea, because then people can upload enormous images that will break the webpage.

Your website should have a max width:

```
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And your images should also:

```
.image {
  max-width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

That way it wont break the screen sizes. If you absolutely *must* have it be full size, even if its 20,000 px wide, then make it a new link thats clicked with `target="_blank"` in a new tab.

```
<a href="file.png" target="_blank"><img src="file.png"></a>
```

As far as the PHP end, there are many guides on how to upload files via PHP. The main thing to take into account is security, as people can embed nasty programs inside uploads, so make sure the example you use has some semblance of security (restricting file extension and mime-type, etc)

Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52663580/794481

Comment: I do have restrictions on the process of uploading an image (file type and file size). I will set a max-width of the wrapper (totally missed that). The target="_blank" idea is great, is the same way in which 9GAG works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can utilize the getimagesize() function to get details about an uploaded image

Example:

```
// Calling getimagesize() function 
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("image.png"); 

// Displaying dimensions of the image 
echo "Width of image : " . $width . "<br>"; 

echo "Height of image : " . $height . "<br>"; 

echo "Image type :" . $type . "<br>"; 

echo "Image attribute :" .$attr;
```

As far as actually displaying the image at its uploaded size, I would have to also say it is a bad idea to do so because your entire layout can break, but maybe what should be done is to create a decent sized thumbnail and use lightbox maybe to display the image at its normal size when clicked.

Comment: I think you are right. I should use either lightbox (the way Facebook images and videos work) or display the image in a new tab (the method that 9GAG uses).

Comment: You could always use fancybox as well which has more display options!