# Update value in database using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is how the table `users` looks like:

```
---------------------------------------------------
|  ID  |  user  |             avatar              |
|  3   |  ane22 |     /img/default-avatar.png     |
|  4   |  cuz33 |     /img/default-avatar.png     |
```

Upload button:

```
<form method="POST" 
              action="" 
              enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            <input type="file" 
                   name="uploadfile" 
                   value="" /> 
  
            <div> 
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Upload"> 
            </div> 
        </form>
```

This is how I am trying to update the profile picture for the current user:

```
} else if ($_POST['action'] == 'Upload') {
    //action for delete
    error_reporting(0); 
      $msg = ""; 
  $name = $_SESSION["user"];/* user */
  
  // If upload button is clicked ... 
  if (isset($_POST['upload'])) { 
  
    $filename = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]; 
    $tempname = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"];     
        $folder = "image/".$filename; 
  
        // Get all the submitted data from the form 
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET avatar='" . $filename . "' WHERE user='" . $name . "'"; 
  
        // Execute query 
        mysqli_query($link, $sql); 
          
        // Now let's move the uploaded image into the folder: image 
        if (move_uploaded_file($tempname, $folder))  { 
            $msg = "Image uploaded successfully"; 
        }else{ 
            $msg = "Failed to upload image"; 
      } 
  } 
  $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users");
```

When I press the `upload` button, nothing happens. And nothing changes in my table also. Any tips?

Comment: Are you sure `isset($_POST['upload'])` is correct?  Have you checked what `$_POST` contains.

Comment: `WHERE user='" . $id . "'` are you sure about it?

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injections, consider using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: If there is any file uploaded ?

Comment: You can try uploading the image first and then update to database.
Something like below:
 if (move_uploaded_file($tempname, $folder))  {
            $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
            mysqli_query($link, $sql); 
        }else{ 
            $msg = "Failed to upload image"; 
      }

Comment: Also please check folder permissions.

Comment: @Cid Yea, I have already used `WHERE user='" . $id . "'` in another query, and it works all fine.

Comment: @NigelRen It should be correct, where should I check it?

Comment: Should I store the image in public_html/img/user.png where `ident`.png is users name? For example: `ane22.png`?

Answer (score 0):

Man you have no action on your form, how do you want it to submit something if the form doesn't do anything...
And also why would you name a variable $id if you store a name in it... That's why "WHERE user = $id" works, because it's not an id it's a name...
Before asking a question in stackoverflow pls try to find your own mistake, or if your error doesn't already exist on it

Comment: Man I don't get any error message, thats why. Doesn't really matter what I name the `$id`, because the value is still the name.

Comment: of course you don't get any error message because if the form has no action it won't load anything. 
PHP doesn't take it as an error, bcs it might be done on purpose, but if you want to make your form upload something, it has to get a link to something

Comment: What do you mean no action? Do you not see the button?

Comment: the button has as action a submit, it's not the action of the form, it's acting like an onclick listener, it just submit to your form when you click on it, so it is supposed to act as the "sender" of the form, but if the form has no receiver, it can't send anything

Comment: You are trying to send data, without saying where/who should get it, that's the problem. You are supposed to declare it on the attribute "action=" of you form

Comment: Sorry, not sure if its because I've been awake for 23 hours, or I'm just blind. Can you post a solution please?

Comment: okay, what's the name/url of your .php where you are supposed to get the data ?

Comment: I have read some, and maybe I should store the images in public_html insted, so; `www.example.com/img/ane22.png` and `www.example.com/img/cuz33.png`

Comment: Okay, I will explain you as easy as possible. When you use a form in php, you are just asking data from the user to enter. There you ask him to give you a .png to send. IF he enters it in the form, and then click on your button, your form get a signal that he should send the data somewhere, THAT'S WHERE THE 
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"> is used, it is supposed to send it to the url that you write on the action="" attribute. So if you don't write the url of your php file that does the treatment (the second part of code that you sent) it won't do anything

Comment: so basically you should just write <form method="POST" action="Verifier.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> where Verifier.php is your php file that upload the .png

Comment: So I can use the code you provided, and customize this(https://stackoverflow.com/a/59169215/14020843) inside Verifier.php?

Comment: you will store the path of the image in you database, not the image, either how will you know which user use which image ? man just go on online classes, and follow tutorials, that's useless to come on stackOverflow for things that can be learnt everywhere

Comment: First of all i am not a "man", and I have tried as you can see, but not sure how to proceed.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
I really tried to explain it as simple as possible, but I can't. Just follow this it will make you learn how to upload your image on your server and then just add the line to insert the path of the image to your database.
But for next programs, try to make your variables names really clear, because if someone else has to read it, or even you have to read it again later, it may introduce you to wrongly understand it